# Converting Functions Deprecated (ereg, ereg_replace, eregi, eregi_replace, split)

Tags: php, function

i have looked into the past topics and read some questions relative of this argument. What i need is just a confirm, i have a lot of pages that uses functions that are deprecated now. I wanto to change those functions but i need to know if this type of changin is correct.

(Example)

```
//Ereg
$pattern = "[[:space:]]";
$replace = "_"; 
$string   = "Hello to Everyone"; 
echo ereg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

To convert into preg_replace can i do this?

```
//Preg
$pattern = "[[:space:]]";
$pattern = '/'.addcslashes($pattern, '/').'/';
$replace = "_"; 
$string   = "Hello to Everyone"; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

I Know that in this example i don't need to use the addcslashes function but sometimes i need to use a pattern with slashes and so i want to understand how to use it.

So if is correct this **'/'.addcslashes($pattern, '/').'/';** or if i Have to change something.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all patterns more or less manually, from what I know no function exists that does this for you.

In any case `addcslashes` is *not* fitting for the job.

Comment: Thanks for thw Answer. 
Just one thing, you say i need to change them manually, and on this i'm in agree, but it's correct to change them with my syntax
`$pattern = '/'.$pattern.'/';`
This is the basic form, also if i have added the **addcskasges** in my example.
I haven't understand why it is not fitting for my problem, is better to strip the slashes manually?